# How to deactivate a specific USB port on Android device

Tags: android, usb, lsusb

I'd like to power on and off a USB device in Android. I know the method on Linux and it is pretty straightforward (see https://loginroot.com/power-off-and-on-usb-device-in-linux-ubuntu/). Unfortunately the command `lsusb -t` does not work on Android terminal.
Do you know how to deactivate a specific USB port on Android? Alternatively, getting the USB device tree should be enough, but I don't know how to achieve that either.